# How to change the Pending warning message

Tags: publishing-site, versioning, content-approval, enterprise-wiki

I am working on an enterprise wiki site collection, and for the versioning setting i defined that the content requires approval, and any user can see the pending pages. so when users add/edit a wiki page they will get the following message at the top of the page:-

[image]

so my question is how i can modify the message text, because i defined that any user can read the pending pages, so the default warning text become misleading "Visitiors can not see this page until it is approved.."?